# change authenticate_token in Authlib to verify token with Authorization server

Tags: flask, flask-restful, authlib

https://docs.authlib.org/en/stable/django/2/api.html#authlib.integrations.django_oauth2.BearerTokenValidator.authenticate_token

From the docs if I understand the flow correctly the authenticate_token method checks the DB for the same token and returns a token.

```
class MyBearerTokenValidator(BearerTokenValidator):
def authenticate_token(self, token_string):
    return Token.query.filter_by(access_token=token_string).first()
```

My question is if the token_string can be verified with the help of the Authorization server instead of checking it against the db?

https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/2/resource-server.html

Comment: This is not checking the db, it is getting the token from db.

Comment: @lepture so that wouldn't work if the Resource server wasn't on the Oauth server right?

Comment: 1. if resource server can access the token database, it will still work

Comment: 2. you can use a token introspection endpoint to handle that

Comment: 3. you can create a RPC server for communication between auth server and resource server. (BTW, we have commercial support plans: https://authlib.org/support